# error : provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server in conecting to aws rds via azure migration service

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to migrate from aws rds to azure via DataMigration service of azure and typed in source SQL Server instance name db_name.cluster.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/schema and got the following error. I opened SQL ports in my computer and I am able to connect to this database.

The ERROR:

```
{ ** "errorType":"Failed to connect, please check error details", "errorDetail":"Error 53 - SQL connection failed.Please use this interactive user guide to troubleshoot the connectivity issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)The network path was not found" }
```

Comment: Did you ever follow this troubleshooting doc:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server? Here list the error message you meet and some common causes.

Comment: yes , did not helped me